# Highlight pdf line

Tags: iphone, pdf, drawing

Please can any one help me. I am really stuck I don't know how to highlight particular line of pdf. It would be better if any one can provide me sample code or pseudo code 
Thanks

Comment: Do you want to modify the PDF file and add highlighting on a particular line, or do you need just to show the PDF on screen with the line highlighted?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HIghlighting the text in PDF document iPhone xcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755584/highlighting-the-text-in-pdf-document-iphone-xcode)

Answer (score 0):

This is not trivial.

To do this, I'd render the PDF contents into one layer, and somehow get the position of the said line/object using the CoreGraphics PDF parser (or some other way). After that, you highlight the said object using your own drawing code.

Answer (score 0):

Just highlighting a particular line is quite difficult.

If you need search and highlight, please try FastPDFKit. I played with it for a while and it's quite good as a pdf reader.

http://mobfarm.eu/fastpdfkit

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on the same thing at the moment and it's not trivial indeed.

From what I can figure out you need to load the text and arrange it in lines first. If you are using Poppler, the `Poppler.Page.textList()` will provide you with a list of TextBoxes and a `TextBox.hasSpaceAfter()` will tell you the end of line when returning `False`.

I am using the Qt4 frontend, so the each TextBox has a QRect from which I can figure out where to highlight a word. Highlighting a line is more or less `lirstWordOfLine.geometry().united(lastWordOfLine.geometry())` which will provide the geometry of the line to highlight.

Now what I can't figure out is how to save the coordinates of the highlights in the document.